# Imply bit with constant 1 or 0 in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bit

Is it possible to express 1 or 0 as a bit when used as a field value in a select statement?

e.g.

In this case statement (which is part of a select statement) ICourseBased is of type int.

```
case 
when FC.CourseId is not null then 1
else 0
end
as IsCoursedBased
```

To get it to be a bit type I have to cast both values.

```
case 
when FC.CourseId is not null then cast(1 as bit)
else cast(0 as bit)
end
as IsCoursedBased
```

Is there a short hand way of expressing the values as bit type without having to cast every time?

(I'm using MS SQL Server 2005)

Answer (score 263, accepted):

```
cast (
  case
    when FC.CourseId is not null then 1 else 0
  end
as bit)
```

The CAST spec is "CAST (expression AS type)". The CASE is an *expression* in this context.

If you have multiple such expressions, I'd declare bit vars @true and @false and use them. Or use UDFs if you really wanted...

```
DECLARE @True bit, @False bit;
SELECT @True = 1, @False = 0;  --can be combined with declare in SQL 2008

SELECT
    case when FC.CourseId is not null then @True ELSE @False END AS ...
```

Comment: To make the code more readable we standardised our SQL and now use declared bit variables when we need to express true/false.

Comment: @Damien McGivern: I found it useful too when I had many CASTs

Comment: Are there any performance-implications of using declared variables? What if you want to use this in a `VIEW` or single-statement table-valued `UDF`?

Comment: @Dai trivial. I did say "multiple such expressions" which is usually a stored procedure

Answer (score 11):

You might add the second snippet as a field definition for ICourseBased in a view.

```
DECLARE VIEW MyView
AS
  SELECT
  case 
  when FC.CourseId is not null then cast(1 as bit)
  else cast(0 as bit)
  end
  as IsCoursedBased
  ...

SELECT ICourseBased FROM MyView
```

Comment: This works, but has the downside that cast() returns a NULL type.

Comment: @Dan There's always `ISNULL( CAST(1 AS bit), CAST(0 AS bit) )` (yes, I'm very frustrated by how verbose SQL is...)

Answer (score 7):

Slightly more condensed than gbn's:

Assuming `CourseId` is non-zero

```
CAST (COALESCE(FC.CourseId, 0) AS Bit)
```

`COALESCE` is like an `ISNULL()`, but returns the first non-Null.

A Non-Zero `CourseId` will get type-cast to a 1, while a null `CourseId` will cause COALESCE to return the next value, 0

Comment: I like the slickness of this solution...  but the original post said nothing about FC.CourseId being non-zero.

Answer (score 6):

No, but you could cast the whole expression rather than the sub-components of that expression. Actually, that probably makes it *less* readable in this case.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the column is BIT and NOT NULL, you should put ISNULL before the CAST.

```
ISNULL(
   CAST (
      CASE
         WHEN FC.CourseId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
      END
    AS BIT)
,0) AS IsCoursedBased
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression to use inside SELECT could be

```
CAST(IIF(FC.CourseId IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) AS BIT)
```

Comment: Make this answer more useful and explain or provide links to library/docs

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. Please explain your answer.

Comment: Although [IIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) looks better than `case when ... else ... end`, one still has to cast `1` and `0` to the BIT type.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.  You will have to cast each value individually.

Answer (score -2):

Tested and functional

```
SELECT fc.CourseId, IsCoursedBased = CAST(CASE WHEN fc.CourseId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) 
FROM fc
```