# How do I return a boolean value from a query during condition evaluation?

Tags: sql-server, boolean

I need something like this:

```
select (len(someLongTextColumn)=0) as isEmpty;
```

The above doesn't work,

any alternatives?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN LEN(SomeLongTextColumn) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IsEmtpy
```

@gbn has good explanation about how to return boolean.

Answer (score 20):

If you cast to bit, then most client code can read it as boolean directly (SQL Server doesn't have a boolean type)

```
SELECT
    CAST(
        CASE
           WHEN len(someLongTextColumn) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END AS bit
        ) as isEmpty;
```

if you have many in one go, use bit variables like this: [Imply bit with constant 1 or 0 in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172795/imply-bit-with-constant-1-or-0-in-sql-server/1172810#1172810)

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server:

```
SELECT CONVERT(BIT, 1) -- true
SELECT CONVERT(BIT, 0) -- false
```

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL 2012 and later, you can use [IIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh213574.aspx) as a shorthand:

```
select IIF(len(someLongTextColumn) = 0, 1, 0) as isEmpty;
```