# ISNULL vs CASE Return Type

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

I recently ran into an interesting issue with changing `CASE` statements to `ISNULL` functions in TSQL. The query I was working with is used to get some user attributes and permissions for a website I work on. Previously the query had a number of `CASE` statements similar to the following:

NOTE: `a.column1` in the example is of type `bit` in the table. Also note that the `[CanDoSomething]` result column is sometimes used as a string in the website.

```
SELECT
    ...
    CASE
        WHEN a.column1 IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE a.column1
    END [CanDoSomething]
    ...
FROM
    a
```

The DBA replaced these `CASE` statements with the `ISNULL` function:

```
SELECT
    ...
    ISNULL(a.column1, 0) [CanDoSomething]
    ...
FROM
    a
```

This seems like a fine change, but it caused something unexpected when retrieving the data in C#. With the previous query, the value of the `[CanDoSomething]` column when accessed from a `DataTable` in C# was `1` or `0`. When we changed to using `ISNULL`, the value in C# was then changed to `true` or `false` which, when treated as a string, are obviously not the same as `1` or `0`.

The errors this caused have already been addressed. I'm just curious why `ISNULL` returns a different value than an equivalent `CASE` statement and I can't seem to find any answers on Google.

Comment: Try using COALESCE(a.column1, 0) instead of ISNULL

Comment: @MuhammedAli For [performance reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408893/using-isnull-vs-using-coalesce-for-checking-a-specific-condtion) (which aren't present in this case), the DBA normally chooses `ISNULL` over `COALESCE`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To  expand on @dasblinkenlight's explanation:

The real issue is that, per [the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx), `case` expressions

> return the highest precedence type from the set of types in
>   *result_expressions* and the optional *else_result_expression*.
>   For more information, see [Data Type Precedence (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx).

While `isnull()`

> returns the same type as *check_expression*

In your case, that is a `bit`. Your `case` expression:

```
CASE
  WHEN a.column1 IS NULL THEN 0
  ELSE                        a.column1
END
```

has execution paths that returns two different data types, an `int` (the literal value `0`) and a `bit` (the value of the column). If you look at the [data type precedence chart](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) linked above, `int` is of higher precedence than `bit` and thus the `bit` value is cast to an `int`.

That is because the conversion from `bit` to `int` is a *widening conversion*. Sql Server's `bit` type essentially, a 1-bit integer value and so no data is lost. The conversion from `int` to `bit` is a *narrowing conversion* and the possibility of data loss exists (at least in concept).

You wouldn't have encountered this problem, if the DBA had used [`coalesce()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) instead of `isnull()`, which would have been my personal choice, as `coalesce()` is defined to return a type similar to that of `case`. `coalesce()`

> Returns the data type of *expression* with the highest data type precedence. If all expressions are nonnullable, the result is typed as nonnullable.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to this is in the [documentation of `ISNULL`'s return type](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx):

> `ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )`
>
> Returns the same type as `check_expression`. If a literal `NULL` is provided as `check_expression`, returns the datatype of the replacement_value. If a literal `NULL` is provided as `check_expression` and no `replacement_value` is provided, returns an `int`.

Unlike your `CASE` expression that <s>always returns an `int`</s> <sup>*</sup> returns an `int` because of zero in the first branch, `ISNULL` will return a value of the type of its first parameter, i.e. `a.column1`.

---

<sup>*</sup> The `CASE` expression was `WHEN a.column1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1` before the edit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think it's not quite what I'm looking for. But you did help me find an error in my question! The documentation states "If a literal NULL is provided as check_expression, returns the datatype of the replacement_value" which means, if I'm reading that correctly, it could return either a bit (if it's not NULL) or an int (if it is NULL and if 0 is treated as an int).

Comment: @jvdub The special case description in the documentation refers to situations when you call `ISNULL(NULL, something)` and `ISNULL(NULL,NULL)`. These are corner case situations that do not make much sense, but the documentation must cover them anyway. Your expression does not provide a literal `NULL` to `check_expression` - it provides `a.column1`, so whatever is the type of that column - that's going to be the return type of `ISNULL`.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm still curious why a `CASE` that can return a `bit` or an `int` only returns and `int` while `ISNULL` returns a `bit`. (see the update to the `CASE` statement int the original question)

Comment: Turns out, to return a `bit` in a `CASE`, you have to cast the whole thing: [Imply bit with constant 1 or 0 in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172795/imply-bit-with-constant-1-or-0-in-sql-server)