# How do I create a bit constant in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I create a bit constant in T-SQL? I tried using Convert(bit, 0) but that is having a weird effect in SSDT.

Comment: what weird effect are you referring to ?

Comment: Actually this is a BS question and should be deleted. The problem I was seeing had nothing to do with using Convert.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried: `CAST(0 AS BIT)`
Also have a look here:
[Imply bit with constant 1 or 0 in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172795/imply-bit-with-constant-1-or-0-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by *a weird effect in SSDT*, but here's two more options you can try:

Using `CAST` instead of convert:

```
CAST(0 AS BIT)
```

Declaring the variables first:

```
DECLARE
   @True BIT,
   @False BIT;
SET @True = 1;
SET @False = 0;
```